# installing android application in device

Tags: android

I finished my application and its run good in eclipse simulator but it couldn’t installed in my device and my friends' devices also. I open the apk file from my drop box and then I couldn't find the logo of my application when the apk uploading finished the run button is invisible and cant click on it and the done button visible, I can see my application in my setting> applications> manage applications > downloaded.. but can only uninstall it and can't see in my applications page . The whole application didn’t installed but the segmentation code by each my friend installed and run on device correctly.?  My application's size is 29 MB

> 1- [2012-05-10 00:26:05 - aya] Android Launch!
>
> 2- [2012-05-10 00:26:05 - aya] adb is running normally.
>
> 3- [2012-05-10 00:26:05 - aya] No Launcher activity found!
>
> 4- [2012-05-10 00:26:05 - aya] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
>
> 5- [2012-05-10 00:26:05 - aya] Performing sync
>
> 6- [2012-05-10 00:26:05 - aya] Automatic Target Mode: using device '37C708442409657'
>
> 7- [2012-05-10 00:26:05 - aya] Uploading aya.apk onto device '37C708442409657'
>
> 8- [2012-05-10 00:26:29 - aya] Installing aya.apk...
>
> 9- [2012-05-10 00:26:44 - aya] Success!
>
> 10- [2012-05-10 00:26:44 - aya] \aya\bin\aya.apk installed on device
>
> 11- [2012-05-10 00:26:44 - aya] Done!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From line 3 of your log (3- [2012-05-10 00:26:05 - aya] No Launcher activity found!) it seems to me that you are missing the following activity declaration in your app's AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".Main Activity Class Name Goes Here">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You may want to read [Android Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) for more information.

Also you may have to enable the "Allow Fake Locations" settings on your device if you have not signed your apk with a non debug key or you are distributing it from non market locations but this is another story...

Hope this helps...

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">"
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Yes OK but where did you find android.intent.action.SPLASH? I cannot find it. Anyway if you want to start an activity named Splash when the user clicks on your app icon then replace the "Main Activity Class Name Goes Here" with Splash in my answer and forget about android.intent.action.SPLASH. Please take a moment and read the "Android Application Fundamentals" link in my answer...

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".MainMenue"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINMENUE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: this is the main activity... by the way my app run very good in my eclipse simulator, and i read "Android Application Fundamentals" which i undretand it before...

Comment: I really appreciate your help because this is my graduation project and  sat is discussion day

Comment: @Nada You are confused about the android.intent.action.MAINMENUE and android.intent.action.SPLASH. You don't have to put the activity name there. android.intent.action.MAIN you see in the examples isn't the android.intent.action. followed by the activity name. It is an action variable which tells to android that the MAIN action has to be performed. Read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Comment: OMG, THANK U SO MUCH, how can i returned your favor. i change the word splash with MAIN... And its going gooooood

Comment: Glad that worked. Good luck on Saturday. No returning favors here, just try to help someone one day that you will have the time...